# As Christians can we support immigration control?

Tags: old-testament, morality, leviticus, deuteronomy

As Christians are we allowed to believe in immigration control or want control as to who enters the country? If yes, then how do you interrupt verses such as these, which seem to support the concept of no borders?:

> The stranger who sojourns with you shall be to you as the native among
> you, and you shall love him as yourself; for you were strangers in the
> land of Egypt: I am the Lord your God.

**Leviticus 19:34**

Love the sojourner therefore; for you were sojourners in the land of Egypt.

**Deuteronomy 10:19**

> Cursed be he who perverts the justice due to the sojourner, the
> fatherless, and the widow.’ And all the people shall say, ‘Amen.

**Deuteronomy 27:19**

Comment: If you have effective immigration control, you won't have sojourners in your land, will you?

Comment: @OneGodtheFather Immigration control doesn't necessarily mean closed borders, though.

Comment: @SupportiveDante What does immigration control mean to you?

Comment: @OneGodtheFather In the most general sense I would define it as "any immigration policy more restrictive than absolutely no restriction at all" Someone on a work or education visa is also a sojourner, no? And such a visa necessarily means immigration control.

Comment: @SupportiveDante Right, so the question would even apply to work visas, student visas, tourism visas, and so on.

Comment: do you have evidence that Christians don't believe/want this (sources)? Countries are diverse makeup of people Christians and non Christians alike

Comment: Sorry, but this is a) clearly opinion based and b) a discussion question.

Comment: @cj564 You will probably have to reword this question, scoping it to immigration views of a specific denomination, say.

Answer (score 2):

The state (as a secular entity) and its inhabitants have interests that they hope to further by establishing immigration controls. Some of these interests are supportable by Biblical principles and some are contradicted.

- Exclusion based on race.
- Exclusion based on religion.
- Exclusion based on insufficient wealth.
- Exclusion based on espousing unpopular political views.
- Exclusion based on low educational and skill level.
- Exclusion based on physical defect.
- Exclusion based on lack of family connection or sponsorship.
- Exclusion based on loyalty to a hostile foreign power.
- Exclusion based on past criminal conduct.
- Exclusion to prevent smuggling of contraband, like unsafe food, illegal or subpar counterfeit drugs, weapons, etc.
- Exclusion based on suspicion or being a terrorist or being related to a terrorist.
- Exclusion based on communicable disease.
- Exclusion based on fear of retaliation by a superior foreign power for harboring a fugitive.
- Exclusion in the midst of an active war.

Almost everyone looking at this list will see some reasons that they find abhorrent but also some which they applaud and can justify Biblically. If even one of the above reasons is supportable, you need immigration laws, controls, defended borders and procedures for immigration, fines, punishments, deportation processes and the like. Then once you have the system, as fashions change, you will see some of the others reasons smuggled in as well. Then it comes down to Christians deciding whether to submit to the governing authories or practice non-violent civil disobedience.

Also, somewhere along the continuum, a few sojourners becomes an invading force, whether military or cultural. Immigration policy decides how many is too many mouths to feed, bodies to house, wounds to treat, and minds to educate. In a welfare state, mass immigration eventually rises to the level of theft.